# FUJITSU E734 change HDD

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have a FUJITSU Lifebook e734. I have to change my drive. But I can't open the Laptop even if i take out all the screws on the bottom.

Thanks in advance...

Jared

Comment: There is supposed to be a cover with one screw you remove to access the hard drive>>>>>>https://www.manualslib.com/manual/721704/Fujitsu-Lifebook-E734.html?page=71#manual

Comment: If you've stripped the screw for that door....I'd remove the screw head with a drill. Be careful not to drill too far though, obviously. xD

Comment: There is no such cover on the e734...